# Узнать процесс родитель

Tags: c#, windows

Подскажите, допустим программа на C# запускает процесс через Process.Start, а запущенный процесс в свою очередь запускает другую программу.
Можно ли среди запущенных процессов найти , тот процесс, который породил процесс запущенный через Process.Start ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить reference на System.Management и

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cmdProcess = Process.Start("cmd");
            Console.ReadLine();

            var query = string.Format("SELECT ProcessId FROM Win32_Process WHERE ParentProcessId = {0}", cmdProcess.Id);
            var search = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", query);

            foreach (var childResult in search.Get())
            {
                var childId = (uint)childResult["ProcessID"];
                var child = Process.GetProcessById((int)childId);

                Console.WriteLine(child.Id + "\t" + child.MainWindowTitle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Если честно - не понял, хотите ли вы найти потомка по родителю или наоборот. Код выше ищет всех потомков для известного родителя.

Если вы знаете потомка, и вам нужно найти его родителя - просто поменяйте местами ProcessId и ParentProcessId в запросе.

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю как с C#, но при помощи WinAPI судя по всему можно.
Перечисляем все процессы через CreateToolhelp32Snapshot + Process32First + Process32Next пока не найдем свой процесс (сравнение своего PID с PROCESSENTRY32.th32ProcessID). Как только получили PROCESSENTRY32 для своего процесса - смотрим поле th32ParentProcessID, которое и будет содержать PID родителя.